# Does anyone know a good hyperbolic geometry software program?

Tags: math-software, hyperbolic-geometry

We are currently using [this program](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~joel/NonEuclid/NonEuclid.html) called NonEuclid but it is a little frustrating to use sometimes and I was wondering if anyone knows another program for hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: 'For hyperbolic geometry' covers an awful lot of terrain - can you be more specific about what features you're looking for?  Do you want 'the stuff that NonEuclid does, only better' or are there particular tools you want available?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I was looking for programs that do things similar to NonEuclid. It is the only program I know that does this sort of modeling and I wanted to know if anyone knows any other similar programs.

Comment: It looks as though there's another set of tools for Cabri; see http://mcs.open.ac.uk/tcl2/nonE/nonE.html for more details.  Cinderella (http://www.cinderella.de/files/HTMLDemos/) also looks to have a hyperbolic geometry package of some sort, but beyond that I'm not seeing much, sadly.  This sort of specialized math software tends to fall by the wayside (and into disrepair) far too quickly.

Comment: I use extensively Ciderella and it is wonderful for the circle model (and for the sphere too!). Of course, it is not free software. I don't know any software for the half-plane model, but I make *ad hoc* constructions with Geogebra

Comment: [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/249859/65915)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe these will help:

[**Geometry Software**](https://web.archive.org/web/20171229130428/http://mathforum.org/geometry/geometry.software.html)

[**The Hyperbolic Toolbox**](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/loci/joma/the-hyperbolic-toolbox-abstract)

[**Cinderella**](https://www.cinderella.de/tiki-index.php)

[**Interactive Non-Euclidean Geometry 1.0**](http://arsenailna.cie.uma.es/%7Eccriado/Interactive%20Non.htm)

Regards -A

Comment: I wasn't aware of these tools! thanks ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: I am familiar to the third and the fourth ones. :-+)

Answer (score 2):

You might check out [Geometry Explorer](http://homepages.gac.edu/~hvidsten/gex/). I recently ran across it and have been impressed by it thus far. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Also you could check this link. You can draw in the poincarè disk model.
https://github.com/Eloind/Hiperbolic-Geometry
I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

During college, a friend and I developped what we called an Hyperbolic Browser which task was to let its users explore the hyperbolic space via multiple models such as :

- Poincaré Disk
- Poincaré Half-Plane
- Beltrami-Klein Disk

With features exclusive to the Poincaré Disk : 
Regular Polygon Tiling generator, and 3 other generations of point.
And the possibility to "move" the points dynamically.

The goal was for us to better understand what was this unorthodox geometry and provide tools to explore for neophytes.

Don't be too harsh on us. The core of the project was designed when we were students.
Going back from the start would have been time-consuming, fastidious and not really interesting for the end-user so the project stands as it is.

Since April 2016, I worked on this maths project on my spare-time with the aim to release the project under a Free and Open Source licence.
After a bit of refactoring and some new features, I'm happy to release what will be version 1.2.

There still are some bugs, the architecture is not perfect (for sure), but at least some features do work.

Feedbacks are wanted and welcomed ! You can download the software directly from the repo.

[Hyperbolic Browser](https://framagit.org/Kii/hyperbolic-browser)

Answer (score 0):

If you google Geogebra hyperbolic geometry then you find several geogebra things/sheets where people have built custom hyperbolic geometry tools. Here was the first search result (to find the custom/user built tools, you click on the "wrench" symbols located on the top right)

https://www.geogebra.org/m/R5e9AggU