# The program "gm" by Epstein and Rumsby for drawing tesselations and Cayley graphs

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

In the book 
[Word Processing in Groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0867202440) by David Epstein, there is a pair of pages, 38 and 39, which have two pictures on them.  If you are familiar with the book, you probably know exactly what I am talking about.  The one is a tessellation of the hyperbolic plane and the other is the Cayley graph of the group produced by the reflections (it is the 2-3-7 coexter group.) In the caption below, it mentions they drew these with the program "gm" which David Epstein and Steve Rumsby wrote.

I was wondering if anyone knew where I could get this program or if they have a copy themselves.  I have looked everywhere I can think to, including the [The geometry center](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/).

Alternatively, is there another program which draws hyperbolic tessellations better than the ones in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108997/does-anyone-know-a-good-hyperbolic-geometry-software-program)?  I have tried all of them, and non-euclid fails after... ahem, "a few" reflections. The others do not seem to want to reflect well in general.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you checked out TikZ? It is a pretty powerful $\LaTeX$ package. I haven't tried to do what you want to do, but I am pretty positive you can. (**EDIT:** You can - see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34547/is-there-a-way-in-tikz-to-reflect-regular-polygons-of-an-arbitrary-number-of-edg) question on TeX.SE)

Comment: I sometimes use the hyperbolic toolbox for Mathematica; after some initial setup, it does pretty well. But it is far from "automatic".  Here's an example: http://imgur.com/8vmDFk0

Comment: @user1729 I was actually hoping for reflections in the hyperbolic plane, which seems very impractical to try to code the pictures I have in mind with TikZ.

Comment: @N.Owad I think it should be fine in TikZ. I programmed a similar thing in postscript a long time ago, and the calculations were not too bad. A printer could compute the tesselations, so I think TeX can. If not, then you could certainly write some short program in a more math oriented language to output the drawing commands. "Reflections" are just circle inversions in the disk model, so very easy to code.

Comment: @N.Owad: Sorry, I thought (2, 3, 7) was Euclidean (didn't think to check!). However, TikZ basically allows you to do anything if you know how. You could try asking at TeX.SE to see if anyone there has any ideas (both for how to do what you want on TikZ and for ideas of any LaTeX packages which are more relevant)?